# Removing underline from p when link covers p, h3 and img

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, underline

Using the http://www.bbc.com/news as an example here. I have an image, header, and paragraph together. I have them all linked within one  tag. I want only the header to be underlined with the hover, but the paragraph is underlined too. I want the header to underline when I hover over the paragraph and image just like on the BBC News website.

```
<a href="link">     
    <img src="" class="main-image" alt="">
    <h3>Underline this on Hover only</h3>
    <p class="front-description">This is a sentence we don't want to be 
        underlined on for any condition</p>
</a>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
a:hover {
    color: #4A310E;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
p.front-description:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the h3 being underlined even when you hover over the picture or paragraph:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover h3{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much for assisting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "a h3:hover" instead of "a:hover". This gets the h3 inside the a tag and only underlines that.

Comment: Just tried that. Close, and a good option for me. Except the header does not underline when I hover over the paragraph, which is what I ultimately am trying to do.